# Cast conversion error on filtered pending changes list

Tags: c#, tfs, .net

**Question Background:**

I am checking in files in VS 2012 TFS programmatically and have developed the following code to filter the pending changes based on a specific file name:

```
internal int CheckinTfsQaItem(IVersionControlItem tfsItem)
    {
        //Get the current workspace info.
        var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(_checkedoutTfsItem.VcQaFolder);

        //Get the TFS project object from the specified server path.
        var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.ServerUri);

        //Get the workspace.
        var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);

        //Filter the pendingChanges object to checkin in only the specified checked out file by it's name.
        PendingChange[] pendingChanges = (PendingChange[])workspace.GetPendingChanges().Where(x => x.FileName == tfsItem.Name);

        //Check in the change, dont set a comment.
        return workspace.CheckIn(pendingChanges, null);
    }
```

**The issue:**

Intellisense does not show any errors but when i debug, I am receiving a cast exception error when attempting to convert a PendingChange singular object to a single list of PendingChange objects, i.e a PendingChanges array.

Here is the error being thrown:

**Result Message:

Test method ADPTestProject.TFStests.Check_Facade_CheckIn_Method threw exception: 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereArrayIterator`1[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PendingChange]'totype 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PendingChange[]'.**

Can anyone tell me why this cast is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PendingChange[] pendingChanges = (PendingChange[])workspace.GetPendingChanges().Where(x => x.FileName == tfsItem.Name);
```

just add a `.ToArray()` at the end of this line.

and remove the cast.

so

```
var pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges()
                              .Where(x => x.FileName == tfsItem.Name)
                              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. It now works perfectly. I will mark your answer as correct when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.ToArray()` this will return your query to an array of `PendingChange`:

```
PendingChange[] pendingChanges = workspace.GetPendingChanges().Where(x => x.FileName == tfsItem.Name).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
workspace.GetPendingChanges().Where(x => x.FileName == tfsItem.Name).ToArray(); //<--
```